# SearchView is crashing on Samsung s6 and galaxy edge note

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, searchview

I used Android Search view in my application and Its working fine on many devices including (HTC M9, HTC Desire 10 pro, Nexus 6, Infinix phone, Nexus 5) but the app is only crashing on Samsung galaxy s6 plus, and Samsung galaxy note edge. The problem is with inflating XML layout, I've searched it on the internet but couldn't find the solution, some suggested to change appCompat to 23.0.2 but it didn't work.

**Crash Log:**

```
10-17 13:45:44.661 19378-19378/com.ingic.aaloo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                             Process: com.ingic.aaloo, PID: 19378
                                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ingic.aaloo/com.ingic.aaloo.activities.ContactSelectionActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #72: Binary XML file line #72: Error inflating class android.widget.SearchView
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3254)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3350)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1795)
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
                                                              Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #72: Binary XML file line #72: Error inflating class android.widget.SearchView
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:551)
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380)
                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292)
                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                                 at com.ingic.aaloo.activities.BaseActivity.setContentView(BaseActivity.java:56)
                                                                 at com.ingic.aaloo.activities.ContactSelectionActivity.onCreate(ContactSelectionActivity.java:70)
                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876)
                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3207)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3350) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1795) 
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229) 
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
                                                              Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #72: Error inflating class android.widget.SearchView
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:657)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:706)
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:774)
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716)
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847)
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:855)
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:855)
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:855)
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:855)
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527)
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292) 
                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                 at com.ingic.aaloo.activities.BaseActivity.setContentView(BaseActivity.java:56) 
                                                                 at com.ingic.aaloo.activities.ContactSelectionActivity.onCreate(ContactSelectionActivity.java:70) 
                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876) 
                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3207) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3350) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1795) 
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229) 
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

**XML Part:**

```
            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true">


                <SearchView
                    android:id="@+id/btn_search"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:searchIcon="@null"
                    android:theme="@style/searchViewTheme" />


                <!--android:searchIcon="@drawable/icon_search"-->
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/btn_search_dummy"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:scaleX="0.85"
                    android:scaleY="0.85"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_search" />

            </FrameLayout>
```

**Dependencies:**

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile files('libs/classes-dex2jar.jar')
compile project(':filebrowser')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.google.guava:guava:14.0.1'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'
compile 'com.andreabaccega:android-form-edittext:1.3.+'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'
compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.2.0'
compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
compile 'org.lucasr.twowayview:twowayview:0.1.4'
compile 'io.pristine:libjingle:9127@aar'
compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:4.2.0'
compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-im:4.2.0'
compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-extensions:4.2.0'
compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android:4.2.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
compile 'io.realm:realm-android-library:3.1.3'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.2.13'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.2.13'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.2.13'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb:2.2.13'
compile 'com.splunk.mint:mint:5.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.4.+'
compile 'com.github.hani-momanii:SuperNova-Emoji:1.1'
compile 'com.github.nekocode:Emojix:1.2'
compile 'com.l4digital.fastscroll:fastscroll:1.0.4'
compile 'com.github.madrapps:pikolo:1.1.6'
compile 'com.github.ozodrukh:CircularReveal:1.1.0'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
compile 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.0.0'
compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'
compile 'com.github.thiagokimo:alexei-library:1.4'
 }
```

**Acitivity Class:**

```
public class ContactSelectionActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @BindView(R.id.rv_selected)
    TwoWayView rvSelected;
    @BindView(R.id.rv_contactlist)
    RecyclerView rv_contactlist;
    @BindView(R.id.txtSelectContacts)
    TextView txtSelectContacts;
    @BindView(R.id.tv_title)
    EmojiconTextView tv_title;
    @BindView(R.id.tv_count)
    TextView tv_count;
    @BindView(R.id.mToolbar)
    View mToolbar;
    @BindView(R.id.btn_search)
    SearchView searchView;
    @BindView(R.id.btn_search_dummy)
    ImageView btnSearchDummy;
    SearchContactAdapter contactAdapter;
    ContactSelectionAdapter selectionAdapter;
    AnimationHelper animationHelper;
    int minCount;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact_selection);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        animationHelper = AnimationHelper.getInstance(this);
//        chatType = ChatType.getType(getIntent().getIntExtra("chatType", 1));

        doSearchRelatedStuff(); 
    }  

    @OnClick({R.id.btn_back})
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btn_back:
                setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, null);
                finish();
                break;

        }
    }

    private void doSearchRelatedStuff() {
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                contactAdapter.filter(newText);
                return false;
            }
        });

        searchView.setOnSearchClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                btnSearchDummy.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                animationHelper.animateSearchToolbar(mToolbar, true, true);
            }
        });
        searchView.setOnCloseListener(new SearchView.OnCloseListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onClose() {
                animationHelper.animateSearchToolbar(mToolbar, false, false);
                btnSearchDummy.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    public void showSearchView(boolean show) {
        if (show) {
            searchView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            searchView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            switch (requestCode) {
                case AppConstants.OPEN_ROOM_ACTIVITY:
//                    listSelectedContacts = data.getParcelableArrayListExtra("contactList");
//                    Intent intent = getIntent();
//                    intent.putExtra("name", data.getStringExtra("name"));
//                    intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("contactList", listSelectedContacts);
                    setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
                    finish();
                    break;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

**Manifest Part:**

```
  <activity
        android:name=".activities.ContactSelectionActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/NoActionBar">

    </activity>
```

Comment: android:theme="@style/searchViewTheme" remove this line and check is it working or not

Comment: It's not working, same error.